# Как подключить несколько токенов в один сценарий бота телеграм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, token

Есть код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("текст"))
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'текст', reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Если вставить второй токен через запятую, то работает только один бот, а нужно, чтобы работали все.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен1',"токен2")
```

Comment: написать класс для бота. и создать 2 экземпляра

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант для каждого бота прописать отлелено переменную
И повторить код для каждой переменной.

Comment: «отлелено» -— это как?

Comment: bot1 = telebot.TeleBot('token1') ; bot2 = telebot.TeleBot('token2')